# Modifying Distribution of Sum of Independent Random Variables to Achieve a Specified Transformation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, gamma-distribution

Consider a random variable $S$ defined as the sum of independent random variables:

${\displaystyle {S = X_{1} + X_{2} + ... + X_{n}}}$

​As $n$ approaches infinity, the prob density of $S$ is given by $f(s)$ for $0 < s < {\infty}$.

We aim to obtain a prob density $g(t)$ such that:

${\displaystyle {g(t) = f(e^t)e^t}， {-\infty} < t < {+\infty}}$.

Question:

How can we adjust the random variable for each step $X_{i}$ to $\hat X_{i}$ or redefine (or modify) $S$, to achieve the desired prob density $g(t)$? We can assume the prob density of $X_{i}$ is $h_{i}(x)$, they belong to the same family of Gamma distribution, but with different parameters.

Comment: Is $f$ a cumulative distribution function or a density or something else?

Comment: $f$ is density. I modified the original post.

Comment: Why would $f(e^t)$ be a probability density a priori? You would have to rescale $f$ as well, because $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{f(y)}{y}dy.$

Comment: Good catch, I made the change.

Comment: When $n$ tends to $+\infty$, according to the central limit theorem, independently the distribution of $X$, $S$ follows the normal distribution and $f$ will be the density function of a normal distribution,

Comment: If $S$ is a positive r.v. with density $f$, then $\ln S$ is a r.v. with density $g$ given by $g(t)=f(e^t)e^t$.

Comment: @NN2, those X are independent, but not iid.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan we are looking for the modification of each step, $X_{i}$ to $\hat X_{i}$, such that summation of those will give $g(t)$

Comment: I get the feeling that this problem is not well-defined as stated. I think we would at least need to know something about the family of distributions $h_i$.

Comment: @Enforce: family of the distributions $h_{i}$ is gamma distribution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. As Christophe Leuridan stated, $\hat{S} := \ln(S)$ has density $g$. If you want an online algorithm that gives you $\hat{S}$, let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Then you can simply define $\hat{S}_1 = \ln(X_1)$ and for $n > 1$ set $\hat{S}_n = \ln(e^{\hat{S}_{n-1}} + X_n)$. Then $\hat{S}_n = \ln(S_n)$ so $\hat{S}_n$ converges to $\ln(S) =\hat{S}$ in probability, $L^p$ or a.s. depending on how $S_n$ converges to $S$ (use the fact that $\ln$ is continuous and increasing and each $X_n$ is positive). Was there something different you wanted?

Comment: @forgottenarrow, Thank you for the comment. I am looking for some kind of summation of random variables such as ${\displaystyle { \hat X_{1} + \hat X_{2} + ... + \hat X_{n}}}$  that will converge to $ln(S)$.

Comment: Hmm, that would be difficult. The problem is that $\ln(S_{n+1}) - \ln(S_n)$ is not independent of $\ln(S_n)$. For that reason, I suspect that for any summation you do get, $\{\hat{X}_i\}$ will not be an independent collection of random variables. If that's ok, you could define $\hat{X}_n = \ln(e^{\hat{S}_{n-1}} + X_n) - \hat{S}_{n-1}$ where $\hat{S}_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \hat{X}_i$. Otherwise, I'm not really sure what can be done. My suspicion is that there may not necessarily exist an independent sequence $\{\hat{X}_n\}$ summing to $\ln(S)$ such that each $\hat{X}_n$ depends only on $X_n$.

Comment: @forgottenarrow, thank you. My general problem is, if $S$ is the summation of random variables $X_{i}$, can $ln(S)$ also be defined as the summation of random variables ? if so, how ?

Comment: I’m assuming you want them to be independent? What if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\hat{X}_k$ has the same distribution as $\ln(S)$ even if it doesn’t equal it?

Comment: @forgottenarrow, "has the same distribution", but does NOT equal it, that is good enough. It will be easier if $\hat X_{n}$ to be independent, but this is NOT required.